# How do I activate a feature + popup when clicking outside of a map in Openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm re-parsing the KML that's already been loaded onto the map similar to the example here:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sundials.html and turning it into a clickable list that will center the map on the point clicked, and display the popup window for it.

*This was really easy to do in Google Maps, but I can't find any similar Openlayers examples. Is there any easier way to do this? Something built-in that I'm missing?*

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="locationTable">
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
 htmlRows = "";
 for(var feat in features) {
     // Build details table 
     featId = features[feat].id; // determine the feature ID     
     title = jQuery(f).filter('[name=TITLE]').text();

     htmlRow = "<li><a href="javascript:selectFeature('"+featId+"');\">"+title+"</a></li>";
     htmlRows = htmlRows + htmlRow;
 }
 jQuery('#locationTable').append(htmlRows);
```

And then for the selectFeature function:

```
function selectFeature(fid) {
    for(var i = 0; i<kml.features.length;++i) {
                     if (kml.features[i].id == fid)
                         {         
                             selected = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(kml.features[i]); 
                             selected.clickFeature(); // make call to simulate Click event of feature
                             break;             
                         }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You were where I am. Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I ended up looping through the KML again and adding links for each element in the table and just using zoomToHere() onClick of each one and pointing it at the coordinates of the centroid. I wasn't able to figure out how to show the popup though.

I also played around with the Bookmark addin which moreless does the same thing: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Addins/Bookmark, but was a lot more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the "selected.clickFeature" call, and instead create an event listener for the "featureselected" event in your feature layer:

[OpenLayers.Layer.Vector](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.EVENT_TYPES)

If you display the popup in that event, you will only have to find it and select it with your existing code, and remove the line
`selected.clickFeature();`

Sidenote: Can your feature server deliver data in other formats? WFS for instance? Parsing KML data shouldn't be needed.