# How to make a clicked link center and show a popup on the map using OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, django, openlayers, geodjango

I've plotted features onto the map from a geojson returned by GeoDjango. I now want to display a list of these features individually. If one is clicked, the map will center in on that particular point and show a popup with some details. A good example would be GoogleMaps, where on the side you have a list of places and clicking on any one of them will show a popup in the map corresponding to that particular place.

This post suggested that one should create an eventListener, so I have tried this but to no avail: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370993/how-do-i-activate-a-feature-popup-when-clicking-outside-of-a-map-in-openlayers)

I'm not sure how to tie these components together. The below code doesn't do anything once a link is clicked. The href is also confusing because it checks my view for a url pattern, so I threw in a void(0) to avoid that.

```
<div id="place-list"></div>
<div id="map"></div>

// ... code that reads a geoJSON and outputs features
var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
vectorLayer.addFeatures(features);

// Build the clickable list of features
var list = "";
for (var i=0, len=features.length; i  len; i++) {
        // This does not work?
        list = list + "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\""+"onclick=\"selectFeature("+i+");\">"+features[i].attributes["address"]+"</a><br/>";
}

    $("#place-list").append(list);  

    var info;
    function selectFeature(i) {
        feature = features[i];
        info = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
            vectorLayer, 
            {
                eventListeners: {
                    getfeaturesinfo: function(event) {
                        map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                            feature.id,
                            feature.lonlat,
                            null,
                            event.text,
                            null,
                            true
                        ));
                    }
                }
            }
        );

    }
    map.addControl(info);
    info.activate();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? Does not call the function? Or function does not do anything useful? You need to debug your JS, use firebug for firefox or web inspector for webkit browsers.

Comment: I found out the function never seemed to be called because I kept getting nulls somewhere. But I later added OpenLayers eventhandlers, and got what I wanted at last!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my problem. I had to create an OpenLayers.Control.Panel which held my links, then add that to my map. For each of the feature objects, I created and linked an eventlistener to each with its id.

And here's a great example of how that's done: [OpenLayers Eventhandler example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/events.html)!